# Is it possible to have <img>'s within <li>'s to be "un-indented"?

Tags: html, css

I have an ordered list `<ol>` with `<li>` elements.  I'm happy with how the lists is currently rendering, but I'd like to make the `<img>` elements within the `<li>`'s not follow the indentation CSS style rules I've set to the `<li>` element.  Is there any way to break the flow of the indentation when it comes to an `<img>` element.

So I have something like:

```
*  List Item 1 description that is two 
   lines long.  Lorem ipsum et dolor.

   |-- IMAGE SPANS WIDTH OF INDENT --|
```

What I want is something like:

```
*  List Item 1 description that is two
   lines long.  Lorem ipsum et dolor.

|-- IMAGES SPANS WIDTH OF <OL> -------|
```

I know I can use negative left margins to shift the image over to the left, but I'd like to avoid using that since it doesn't effect the width of the element.  Any suggestions are appreciated!

Comment: Next time, use ``backticks (`)`` to escape HTML tags.

Comment: @jnylen why do I need to use backticks?

Comment: @Robert Harvery that would work, but there are cases where there is text that flows after the image.  The image doesn't always trail the text.

Comment: `why do I need to use backticks?` -- Because the Markdown editor will swallow most of your html tags if you don't.

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is some css positioning trickery:

```
ul {
position:relative;
}

ul img {
position:absolute;
left:0;
}
```

Basically what this does is set the image `position` to `absolute` (ie, anywhere) but setting the parent `UL` to `relative`, means that any children set to `absolute` will see the `UL`'s dimensions as their viewport. so Setting `left` to `0` on the image will set it to the left most part of the `UL`

Comment: or play with the left: value to your desired effect.

Comment: That works, but not if the image is in between two `<p>` elements.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap image in a `DIV`, set negative `margin-left` for this `DIV` instead of the image, and then you will be able to set `width` of image equal to 100% of the list.